# How can I improve this code? Prompt user input [Rust]

Tags: optimization, rust, user-input

I am learning Rust by just coding right after the first 4 chapters of The Book.  Getting started I am still getting used to how borrowing and sharing work and how we can take advantage of them in code.

This snippet of code is supposed to prompt user for an IP address, and if enter is pressed, then to return the loopback address.  It works fine, but I am curious to know how this could be improved in any ways, because I definitely know it can.  Thank you!

```
fn prompt_host() -> String {
   let mut input_text = String::new();
   println!(" input host IP, press enter for loopback:");
   io::stdin()
     .read_line(&mut input_text)
     .expect(" ERROR: failed to read from stdin");
   let len = input_text.len();
   input_text.truncate(len - 1);
   if input_text == "" {
      return String::from("127.0.0.1");
   }
   return input_text as String;
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just some hints:

- I think I would return something related to [`std::net::IpAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.IpAddr.html) instead of `String` (if there's a type for your needs, I would use it).
- [`std::net::IpAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.IpAddr.html) implements [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.IpAddr.html#impl-FromStr), so you can use `input_text.parse()` and obtain a `Result<IpAddr, Err>` (since the conversion from string may fail).
- I would use [`trim`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.trim) to get rid of spaces.
- I would use `is_empty` to test if the string is empty. - Or even cover this case by just using `parse`.
- There are (at least) two places that may fail: `read_line` and `parse`, so I would think about returning an `Option<IpAddr>` or even `Result<IpAddr, ErrorType>` for an appropriate `ErrorType`.